# Outlook PHP HTML e-mail

Tags: php

when i try send mail by my php script to outlook in header i see somethink like that "globalthie@k14.unixstorm.org; w imieniu; od kogoĹ› "

but in headers i have only

```
$headers  = 'From: od kogoś ' . $from . "\r\n";
```

I don't know what that happen.
Here is the PHP code to send the mail:

```
$check_date = array(
    'Nazwa drużyny'                 => 'team_name',
    'Imię i nazwisko kapitana'      => 'name_surname_capitan',
    'Telefon kontaktowy'            => 'phone_number',
    'E-mail kontaktowy'             => 'mail_contact',
    'Miejscowość'                   => 'city',
    'Imię i nazwisko zawodnika 1'   => 'name_surname_player_01',
    'Imię i nazwisko zawodnika 2'   => 'name_surname_player_02',
    'Imię i nazwisko zawodnika 3'   => 'name_surname_player_03'
);

$errors = array();
$i      = 0;

if(isset($_POST['check_click'])){

    foreach($check_date as $table => $key){
        if(empty($_POST[$key])){
            $errors[$i++] = 'Proszę o uzupełnienie pola: <div class="error">'.$table.'</div>';
        }
    }

    if(count($errors) == 0){
        $from       = '<test@wp.pl>';
        $to         = 'thomas.thiel@global-thiel.com';
        $subject    = 'Test wiadomości';
        $message    = '
            Nazwa druzyny: '.$_POST['team_name'].' <br />
            Imię i nazwisko kapitana: '.$_POST['name_surname_capitan'].'<br />
            Telefon kontaktowy: '.$_POST['phone_number'].'<br />
            E-mail kontaktowy: '.$_POST['mail_contact'].'<br />
            Miejscowość: '.$_POST['city'].'<br />
            Imię i nazwisko zawodnika 1: '.$_POST['name_surname_player_01'].'<br />
            Imię i nazwisko zawodnika 2: '.$_POST['name_surname_player_02'].'<br />
            Imię i nazwisko zawodnika 3: '.$_POST['name_surname_player_03'].'<br />
        ';

        $headers  = 'From: od kogoś ' . $from . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . "\r\n";
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

        echo "
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert('E-mail został pomyślnie wysłany');
            </script>";
    }else{
        foreach($errors as $table){
            echo $table.'<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actully in accordance with RFC 2822. , you should be using `"\r\n"`

Comment: @Dagon, True. Maybe it's a full stop issue.